# conversion of Crystal reports to SSRS without database access

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a few Crystal reports which needs to be converted to SSRS, but I don't have access to database. Is it possible to do the conversion without database access? If yes, how to assign datasets to the report?

Comment: Without database access? You mean you can't even run the reports?

Comment: I can just preview some of the reports. I can just see the tables used, but can't even see the SQL Query.